# Updating an item and changing foreign key

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Have `subjects` and `category` tables.

In the `subjects` table I have a `CategoryId` column and it is a foreign key to the `category` table.

When I try to update a subject using the code shown here, nothing happens:

```
Subject subject;

using (var ctx = new SubjectEntities())
{
    subject = ctx.Subjects.Where(s => s.CategoryId == kategorijaId).FirstOrDefault<Subject>();

    if (subject != null)
    { 
        subject.CategoryId = kategorijaId;
        subject.FullName = ime;
        subject.WebSite = web;
        subject.PhoneNumber = tel;
        subject.E_MAIL = mejl;
    }

    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Some help ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `context.Entry(subject).State = EntityState.Modified;` before saving changes.

Comment: It updates everything except categoryId. CategoryId is a foreign key to the category table.